# Regular expression for multiple rows

Tags: c#, regex

I have a C# program that goes through SAS logs and I want it to pull out the rows with an error.

For example if my log file has these rows:

```
WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro EDIT_TEXT not resolved.

ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.

ERROR: SAS ended due to errors.
   You specified: OPTIONS ERRORABEND;.
ERROR: Errors printed on page 4.

NOTE: SAS Institute Inc., SAS Campus Drive, Cary, NC USA 27513-2414
NOTE: The SAS System used:
  real time           1.37 seconds
  cpu time            0.38 seconds
```

I want to get back

```
ERROR: SAS ended due to errors. You specified: OPTIONS ERRORABEND;.
ERROR: Errors printed on page 4.
```

but it is only returning

```
ERROR: SAS ended due to errors.
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
Match match;
Regex regex;
StreamReader sr;
string log;

sr = new StreamReader(path + ".log");
log = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
regex = new Regex("ERROR: [^\\r]+\\r");
match = regex.Match(log);
```

I'm not sure what to change on the regular expression to fix it.  Thanks

Comment: Use [`(?m)^ERROR: .*(?:\n(?!ERROR: ).*)*`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5eERROR%3a+.*%28%3f%3a%5cn%28%3f!ERROR%3a+%29.*%29*&i=ERROR%3a+SAS+ended+due+to+errors.%0d%0a+++You+specified%3a+OPTIONS+ERRORABEND%3b.%0d%0aERROR%3a+Errors+printed+on+page+4.&o=m). Or, split with `(?m)^(?=ERROR: )`

Comment: How can the regex know that the following line belongs to the error message? Is it because it's indented? I think you need to provide a larger example that also contains lines you don't want to extract, otherwise it will be difficult to find a rule that works.

Comment: Hi Tim,  I updated my original post with more text from the log.

Comment: Just a side note: I would be very careful with reading the whole log in a string, since it can be too big.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up IIya.  Our process has many small logs.  They won't be too big to where the performance decreases.

Comment: Wiktor,  Using the updated log text  (?m)^ERROR: .*(?:\n(?!ERROR: ).*)*  only returns 2 of the error rows and it returns the notes rows as well.  How can I change the regular expression to only get the ERROR rows?  Thank you

Comment: Try `^ERROR: .*(?:\n(?![A-Z]+: ).*)*` or more specific, excluding known beginnings of lines - `^ERROR: .*(?:\n(?!(ERROR|NOTE|WARNING): ).*)*`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this Regex. If you have more than NOTE: or ERROR:, you should add them in a similar way.

`ERROR:(.*\n?.*)(NOTE:|ERROR:)?`

And this regex has the information of the error stored in Group 1.

Second , non regex approach:

```
   string yourLogText = "you log text";

   string[] lines = yourLogText.Split(new string[1] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
   string builtErrorText = "";
   Boolean isBuildingError = false;

   List<String> resultingErrors = new List<string>();
   for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
   {
       if (lines[i].StartsWith("ERROR:"))
        {
          isBuildingError = true;

         if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(builtErrorText))
               resultingErrors.Add(builtErrorText);

          builtErrorText = lines[i];
       }
       else if (lines[i].StartsWith("NOTE:") || lines[i].StartsWith("WARNING:"))
       {
            isBuildingError = false;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(builtErrorText))
                 resultingErrors.Add(builtErrorText);
       }
       else if (isBuildingError)
       {
           // If you want them to appear on different lines.
           builtErrorText += Environment.NewLine + lines[i];
        }
      }
    }

    // In case it ends with an error
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(builtErrorText))
        resultingErrors.Add(builtErrorText);
```

Comment: What if there are more than two lines pertaining to 1 error? What if there are WARNING lines between ERROR lines?

Comment: I am not sure if everyhing you want can be done via one regex. I added a second solution that does not use regex, but it works, and you  can adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Thank you Lupu.    I have it working with this "ERROR: .*(?:\n).*"  so far.  If it doesn't work I'm going to use your non-regex approach.  Thank you